# Why does std::vector zero initilize its memory?

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, vector, std

I recently noticed that `std::vector` does clear it's memory with zeros after allocating.

I have created similar containers before (although not `std` compliant) and I never needed to explicitly zero the memory before creating new items.

I can't see a reason to do that and I was just wondering why.

To illustrate :

```
struct S {
    int s[128];
};

bool vector_zeroed() {
    std::vector<S> c;
    while(c.size() < 1000) {
        c.emplace_back();
    }

    bool zeroed = true;
    for(const auto& s : c) {
        for(int i : s.s) {
            zeroed &= i == 0;
         }
    }
    return zeroed;
}

bool array_zeroed() {
    bool zeroed = true;
    auto *s = new S[1000];
    for(int k = 0; k != 1000; ++k) {
        for(int i : s[k].s) {
            zeroed &= i == 0;
        }
    }
    delete[] s;
    return zeroed;
}
```

`vector_zeroed()` seems to always return `true` while `array_zeroed()` returns `false`.

I am obviously missing something here but i don't know what.

Comment: Does this happen in release mode?

Comment: How did you create the vector?  if you used `reserve` it should not have zeroed the memory.

Comment: Please be more explicit.  What *exactly* did you notice?  What code *exactly* made you notice it?  I can create situations where `std::vector`s does not zero memory.  I can create situations where a `std::vector`s does zero memory.

Comment: @NathanOliver: If you use `reserve`, then it doesn't create the objects there. It just reserves space. He's asking about creating objects without initializing their data.

Comment: @NicolBolas: You don't _know_ that. Indeed, his second paragraph suggests otherwise to me.

Comment: @NicolBolas Are you sure?  It looks like he just wants a uninitialized chunk of memory to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CPP reference documentation:

the below overloaded constructors **zeroes out elements of non-class types such as int, which is different from the behavior of new[] , which leaves them uninitialized.**

```
explicit vector( size_type count );   (since C++11)  (until C++14)
explicit vector( size_type count, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
(since C++14)
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector

Comment: This may be what i am looking for. new[] leave the elements uninitialized whereas new[](); does not. TIL

Answer (score 5):

When creating an `std::vector` with n elements (as opposed to just using `reserve` to reserve space for them without actually creating), the default constructor is invoked on each of the elements. In the case of number primitives (such as `int`s or `double`s) the action of the default constructor is to set the value to zero.